# Tmux transparent status bar

Tags: tmux

I'm not sure it this is possible but I use a graphical terminal emulator that has a translucent background so I can see the GUI windows behind it (in this case tinted a shade of blue).  I want my status Line to have this as its background color.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I was able to find this useful example: http://jasonwryan.com/blog/2010/01/07/tmux-terminal-multiplexer/

And it used the color `default`.

so what I wanted was:

```
set status-bg default
```

EDIT: this might not work in newer versions of tmux, see other answers below

Comment: `set -g status-bg default` worked for me.

Answer (score 43):

The accepted answer from olleicua (to be more specific, the comment from sammy) stopped working for me as of tmux 3.2.

I changed the line to the following and now it's working again:

```
set-option -g status-style bg=default
```

The ["3.2 questions and comments" thread](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/2645) on the official github page explains why this is the case:

> `status-fg` and `status-bg` are now applied before `status-style` rather than instead of; this means that if either is set to `default` the `status-style` colour will be used. To fix, replace `status-bg default` with `status-style bg=default`.